"list index out of range" and "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" errors while updating tags for an AWS account in a separate app
I am writing a script that will take the tags from our AWS account repository and then add the same tags for the account to another app thats called example.org. When I run the script, its working for some accounts but for some of them, its giving me "list index out of range" and "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" errors. I am unable to figure out whats the issue here and need some help to resolve this. I understand I may have to provide additional information but lets start with this. In the below code label is like an account identifier and repoData is from where the tags are fetched.
def add_tags(headers, label, repoData):
    existing_tag = []
    new_list = []
    value_quote = []
    get_url = f'https://example.org/applications?$search="displayName:{label}"'
    headers = "some random value"
    response1 = requests.get(url=get_url, headers=headers)
    res = response1.json()
    print(res)
    if response1.status_code == 200:
        if res.get("value"):
            old_tags = res["value"][0]["tags"]
            for i in old_tags:
                existing_tag.append(i)
                value_quote = ['"{}"'.format(i) for i in existing_tag]
    
        tags = {
            "SECONDARYCONTACT": repoData["account"]["sec_email_address"],
            "PRIMARYCONTACT": repoData["account"]["primary_email_address"],
            "COUNTRY": repoData["account"]["countryID"],
            "ENVIRONMENT": repoData["account"]["work_load"],
            "APPID": repoData["account"]["application_id"],
            }
        tags_list = [
            '"{}:{}"'.format(key, value.lower() if value is not None else None)
            for key, value in tags.items()
        ]
        new_list = tags_list + value_quote
        tags = '"tags": [{}]'.format(", ".join(new_list))
        patch_data = "{{{}}}".format(tags)
        appId = res["value"][0]["appId"]
        time.sleep(30)
        patch_url = "https://example.org/applications(appId='{" + appId + "}')"
        response2 = requests.patch(url=patch_url, data=patch_data, headers=headers)
    return response2


Please show the full traceback so we know which lines are getting these errors.

If res["value"][0]["tags"] is None, you'll get the second error from for i in old_tags.

appId = res["value"][0]["appId"] is not inside if res.get("value"):. So it can get the "list index out of range" error if res["value"] is an empty list.

Since you print res at the beginning of the loop body, you should be able to see which conditions are occurring that will causes these errors. You might want to use pprint(res) so it's easier to see the structure.

You are right. For the accounts where I am getting the error, the res is : { 'https://example.com/$metadata#applications', 'value': []}. How can I handle this in the script?

Put the code that's getting the error inside that if statement, so it won't run when value is empty.

What should the patch_url be if there's no value for that account?

Dont want the patch to run if the value is empty

@Barmar could you please suggest the edits to my script so that the tags are updated only if the res has values inside it

So what should response2 be in that case?

requests.patch operation will only run if the res has any values. If the values comes out to be empty, I just want to skip everything and just print that the account has no metadata.

You also shouldn't use all that string formatting to create the data for requests.patch(). It looks like you're trying to create JSON, you should use the built-in JSON formatter for that.

All the rest of the function should be inside the if condition that checks that res.get("value") is not empty.
You can simplify the code by combining that check with the status code check.
def add_tags(headers, label, repoData):
    existing_tag = []
    new_list = []
    value_quote = []
    get_url = f'https://example.org/applications?$search="displayName:{label}"'
    headers = "some random value"
    response1 = requests.get(url=get_url, headers=headers)
    res = response1.json()
    print(res)
    if response1.status_code == 200 and res.get("value"):
        old_tags = res["value"][0]["tags"]
        for i in old_tags:
            existing_tag.append(i)
            value_quote = ['"{}"'.format(i) for i in existing_tag]

        tags = {
            "SECONDARYCONTACT": repoData["account"]["sec_email_address"],
            "PRIMARYCONTACT": repoData["account"]["primary_email_address"],
            "COUNTRY": repoData["account"]["countryID"],
            "ENVIRONMENT": repoData["account"]["work_load"],
            "APPID": repoData["account"]["application_id"],
            }
        tags_list = [
            '"{}:{}"'.format(key, value.lower() if value is not None else None)
            for key, value in tags.items()
        ]
        new_list = tags_list + value_quote
        tags = '"tags": [{}]'.format(", ".join(new_list))
        patch_data = "{{{}}}".format(tags)
        appId = res["value"][0]["appId"]
        time.sleep(30)
        patch_url = "https://example.org/applications(appId='{" + appId + "}')"
        response2 = requests.patch(url=patch_url, data=patch_data, headers=headers)
        return response2
    else:
        print("No metadata found, account not patched"


Thank you. Now I am getting "cannot access local variable 'response2' where it is not associated with a value". Also the "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" still exists.

In my last edit I fixed the indentation of return response2. Are you using the version before that?

Which line is getting the "not subscriptable" error?

I think its coming from 1 of the other methods in my code. LEt me find that out and see how I can share that with you. Please give me some time. I appreciate all the help

Now that you understand the problem in this code, it seems like you should be able to debug that code yourself. We shouldn't have to go through this process with every part of your application -- if we do, you need to hire a real programmer to do this for you.

I undersatnd. Thanks for your help
